# Sending a JFrame drawing from Client to Server using sockets

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jframe

I'm trying to send my java file where I have a JFrame drawing with button that changes the color of the background from Client to Server. The server recieves that Drawing and opens it but when I click buttons nothing change. What am I doing wrong? Also for some reason the app doesn't run sometimes.

Code with the drawing

```
package Drawings;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawingTwo extends JFrame {


    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 300;

    public Color tvColor;
    public Color smileColor;
    public int h;
    public int h2;
    public int h3;
    public int h4;
    public int h5;
    public int h6;
    public String l;
    public DrawComponent c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawingTwo();
            }
        });

    }

    public DrawingTwo() {
        super();
        setOneChanell();

        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setBackground(new Color(242, 212, 252));
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));
        container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT));

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

        JLabel lb = new JLabel(l);
        lb.setText(l);
        container.add(lb);
        JButton j2 = new JButton("2");
        j2.addActionListener(listener);
        container.add(j2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        c = new DrawComponent();
        container.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setOneChanell() {
        this.tvColor = new Color(255, 153, 153);
        this.smileColor = new Color(255, 247, 10);
        this.h = 110;
        this.h2 = 55;
        this.h3 = 60;
        this.h4 = 60;
        this.h5 = 0;
        this.h6 = -180;
        this.l = "Канал для веселых";
    }

    public void setTwoChanell() {
        this.tvColor = new Color(172, 194, 157);
        this.smileColor = new Color(0, 161, 219);
        this.h = 115;
        this.h2 = 87;
        this.h3 = 50;
        this.h4 = 40;
        this.h5 = 0;
        this.h6 = +180;
        this.l = "Канал для грустных";
    }

    public class DrawComponent extends JComponent {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(37, 26, 210, 130);

            g.setColor(tvColor);
            g.fillRect(42, 30, 200, 120);

            g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
            g.fillRect(135, 156, 15, 20);

            g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
            g.fillRect(83, 170, 120, 13);


            g.setColor(smileColor);
            g.fillOval(100, 45, 80, 80);


            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawArc(120, 70, 10, 10, 0, 360);
            g.drawArc(150, 70, 10, 10, 0, 360);

            g.drawString(l, 83, 200);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawArc(h, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6);
        }

    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
            if (button.getText().equals("2")) {
                setTwoChanell();
                button.setText("1");

            } else {
                setOneChanell();
                button.setText("2");
            }
            c.repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

THis is Client file

```
package ClientToServer;

import java.io.*;

import java.net.Socket;

import Drawings.DrawingTwo;


public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(new DrawingTwo());
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();
    }


}
```

This is Server file

```
package ClientToServer;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import Drawings.DrawingTwo;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Server {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

        DrawingTwo object = (DrawingTwo) inputStream.readObject();
        object.setVisible(true);
        object.setTitle("Server");
        object.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.close();
        inputStream.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ Among other things: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: You need to re-attach / reestablish your button listeners on the server side.

Comment: The `Drawing2` constructor is run on the client, which means all the initialization contained therein makes sense for the client. I'm unsure what you're trying do by sending this object to another device.

Comment: @trashgod made some changes to the Drawing file

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it's for my class, just one of the tasks

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out what functionality you are trying to achieve,

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk i'm sending my drawing app to the server so when the app is running on server  the button can still be accessed to change the colors, lines etc. My teacher basically stated "send the drawing to the server so server could have some fun pressing buttons"

Comment: You need to rethink this. The constructor for `Drawing2` needs to run on the server, sending a client-constructed JFrame to the server doesn't really do anything. You don't need to "send" anything, the server can just run `new Drawing2()` to get the same basic GUI.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk how can I run Drawing2 on the server then? What exactly do I need to change?

Comment: *"send the drawing to the server so server could have some fun pressing buttons"* I'd interpret that to mean 'send a `BufferedImage`' rather than 'send a GUI showing some custom rendering'.. Either a `BufferedImage` or the 'model' used to create the painting, which only seems to encompass the variables seen in this call: `g.drawArc(h, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6);` & the two color attributes. Either an image or model would be simpler and less bytes to transfer, than sending a GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read about socket communications a bit more. If you have a server socket, it should run all the time. In your code you close your socket connection right after you receive the data from client.

Another thing is; you have limited your communication with only one type: DrawingTwo() class. On your server side, you cannot receive any other data.

Let's take a look step by step on your code.

**You must define a new object for communication purposes**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CommunicationObject implements Serializable{
    
    private DrawingTwo mDrawingTwo;
    private boolean mSmileyFace = true;
    private boolean mIsInitialConnection = true;
    
    
    public DrawingTwo getmDrawingTwo() {
        return mDrawingTwo;
    }
    public void setmDrawingTwo(DrawingTwo mDrawingTwo) {
        this.mDrawingTwo = mDrawingTwo;
    }
    public boolean ismSmileyFace() {
        return mSmileyFace;
    }
    public void setmSmileyFace(boolean mSmileyFace) {
        this.mSmileyFace = mSmileyFace;
    }
    public boolean ismIsInitialConnection() {
        return mIsInitialConnection;
    }
    public void setmIsInitialConnection(boolean mIsInitialConnection) {
        this.mIsInitialConnection = mIsInitialConnection;
    }   
}
```

You have 3 fields here.

1. DrawingTwo; is your actual layout
2. boolean SmileyFace; indicates your button's situation
3. boolean IsInitialConnection; decides whether it is initialization so your Server inits layout or changes the smiley face

**Your server must listen all the time**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Server {

    static boolean isRunning = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket client = null;
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        DrawingTwo drawingTwo = null;
        CommunicationObject communicationObject = null;

        while (isRunning) {
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

            is = client.getInputStream();

            communicationObject = (CommunicationObject) inputStream.readObject();

            if (communicationObject.ismIsInitialConnection()) {
                drawingTwo = (DrawingTwo) communicationObject.getmDrawingTwo();
                drawingTwo.setVisible(true);
                drawingTwo.setTitle("Server");
                drawingTwo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            } else {                

                if (communicationObject.ismSmileyFace()) {
                    drawingTwo.setOneChanell();                     
                } else {
                    drawingTwo.setTwoChanell();                     
                }
                drawingTwo.c.repaint();

            }

        }
        client.close();
        inputStream.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Please note that **isRunning** is always true now. You must handle the exceptions and other situations to stop it or restart it.

**Create a getter for your JButton in your DrawingTwo class**

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public class DrawingTwo extends JFrame{

      public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 300;
        public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 300;

        public Color tvColor;
        public Color smileColor;
        public int h;
        public int h2;
        public int h3;
        public int h4;
        public int h5;
        public int h6;
        public String l;
        public DrawComponent c;
        
        
        private JButton j2;
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new DrawingTwo();
                }
            });

        }
        
        public DrawingTwo() {
            super();
            setOneChanell();

            Container container = getContentPane();
            container.setBackground(new Color(242, 212, 252));
            container.setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));
            container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT));

            ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

            JLabel lb = new JLabel(l);
            lb.setText(l);
            container.add(lb);
            j2 = new JButton("2");
            j2.addActionListener(listener);
            container.add(j2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            c = new DrawComponent();
            container.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
                        
           
        }
        
        public void setOneChanell() {
            this.tvColor = new Color(255, 153, 153);
            this.smileColor = new Color(255, 247, 10);
            this.h = 110;
            this.h2 = 55;
            this.h3 = 60;
            this.h4 = 60;
            this.h5 = 0;
            this.h6 = -180;
            this.l = "1";
        }

        public void setTwoChanell() {
            this.tvColor = new Color(172, 194, 157);
            this.smileColor = new Color(0, 161, 219);
            this.h = 115;
            this.h2 = 87;
            this.h3 = 50;
            this.h4 = 40;
            this.h5 = 0;
            this.h6 = +180;
            this.l = "2";
        }
                
        public JButton getJButton() {
            return j2;
        }


        public class DrawComponent extends JComponent {
            
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(37, 26, 210, 130);

                g.setColor(tvColor);
                g.fillRect(42, 30, 200, 120);

                g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                g.fillRect(135, 156, 15, 20);

                g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                g.fillRect(83, 170, 120, 13);


                g.setColor(smileColor);
                g.fillOval(100, 45, 80, 80);


                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawArc(120, 70, 10, 10, 0, 360);
                g.drawArc(150, 70, 10, 10, 0, 360);

                g.drawString(l, 83, 200);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawArc(h, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6);
            }

        }
        
        public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
                if (button.getText().equals("2")) {
                    setTwoChanell();
                    button.setText("1");

                } else {
                    setOneChanell();
                    button.setText("2");
                }
                c.repaint();
            }

        }
}
```

Remember that you have 2 functionalities for your button

1. Change the layout on your client, which you have already handled
2. Send the signal to your server, so it can change it too

**At last, the Client class.**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Client {
    
    static OutputStream outputStream;
    static ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    static Socket socket;    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        
        DrawingTwo drawingTwo = new DrawingTwo();
        
        CommunicationObject communicationObject = new CommunicationObject();        
        communicationObject.setmDrawingTwo(drawingTwo);
        communicationObject.setmIsInitialConnection(true);
        
        write(communicationObject);
                
        JButton button = drawingTwo.getJButton();
        
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {
                    if (button.getText().equals("2")) {
                        
                        communicationObject.setmIsInitialConnection(false);
                        communicationObject.setmSmileyFace(false);
                        write(communicationObject);
                    } else {
                        communicationObject.setmIsInitialConnection(false);
                        communicationObject.setmSmileyFace(true);
                        write(communicationObject);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    public static void write(CommunicationObject comObject) throws IOException
    {       
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
                
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(comObject);
        
        objectOutputStream.flush();     
        objectOutputStream.close();
    }   
}
```

You create a CommunicationObject here and assign your DrawingTwo class to it.

Take a look where you extract the **JButton** from **DrawingTwo** into **Client** class, so you can bind ActionListener to it. From this action listener you can now communicate with your server.

**NOTE**
Since both Client and Server has access to DrawingTwo, you don't need to send whole class via socket. Just send a message to Server, that it should create an instance by itself.